# How do I run LiveUSB with Persistence so it loads everything into RAM and runs from that?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

Noob here.
I am looking for a way to use the 6 gigs of RAM in my system. I am primarily using a live USB environment with persistence enabled. I was wondering if there is a way to have the OS loaded into the RAM, thus reducing read write to the pendrive.... and yet retain persistence.

Comment: So you want the persistent OS on the live USB to always load into RAM and then only save back to the USB pendrive at shutdown?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for making the title a lot more descriptive.